# Transform struct to slice struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, reflect

I'm trying to select a struct by string input and then depending on the return JSON Object or Array, unmarshall the JSON. Is it correct to think of a way to reflect the struct to slice struct? if so how to do that with reflection?
Regards,
Peter

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type NameStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {

    jsonData := []byte(`[{"name":"james"},{"name":"steven"}]`)
    returnModel := InitializeModel("NameStruct", jsonData)
    fmt.Println(returnModel)

    jsonData = []byte(`{"name":"james"}`)
    returnModel = InitializeModel("NameStruct", jsonData)
    fmt.Println(returnModel)

}

func getModelByName(modelType string) interface{} {
    modelMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    modelMap["NameStruct"] = new(NameStruct)

    //don't want to do this
    modelMap["arrNameStruct"] = new([]NameStruct)
    return modelMap[modelType]
}

func InitializeModel(modelName string, jsonData []byte) interface{} {
    switch IsArray(jsonData) {
    case true:
        // some conversion here, how?
        returnModel := getModelByName("NameStruct")
        if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &returnModel); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        return returnModel
    case false:
        returnModel := getModelByName("NameStruct")
        if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &returnModel); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        return returnModel
    }
    return nil
}

func IsArray(jsonData []byte) bool {
    return (bytes.HasPrefix(jsonData, []byte("["))) && (bytes.HasSuffix(jsonData, []byte("]")))
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea, is there a particular problem you're trying to solve? For example in your code what would be the *concrete* advantage over using the initialization primitives provided by the language? e.g. https://play.golang.com/p/JlSdzo7uyN_L

Comment: I have around 50 structs. This would give me 100 lines of code in the 'getModelByName' function. I think there is a better way....I'm trying to resolve that sometimes I get a object json back, and sometimes a array json that points to the same struct to unmarshall.

Comment: If you actually need to do something meaningful with the returned `returnModel` you'll have to type-assert the value, which, it seems to me, completely defeats the purpose of the `getModelByName`. I can see the `getModelByName` approach make sense only in the case where you don't care much about the underlying type and you just need to pass the data on to somewhere, *in another format*, say, for example, converting json to xml.

Comment: What i'm trying to accomplish is, I have about 50 api endpoints that I need to unmarshall. e.g. 1 endpoint can return an json object with fields, and that same endpoint can sometimes return an array with the same object fields. So if it's an object I can unmarshall it into a NameStruct and if it's an array into a []NameStruct but I don't want to declare 2 structs because they hold the same fields.

Comment: @mkopriva ah - thought one could do this at the package level - looks like it's only possible when starting with a particular struct value or it's native fields. I guess a `Register` function would be the least boiler-plate way to achieve this then.

Comment: Can u give an example plz? @colminator

Comment: @Peterpanman If you don't care about the underlying types then here you go: https://play.golang.com/p/n2LqF_dUwvU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can create a `Factory` where pre-defined types are registered:

```
type Factory struct {
    m map[string]reflect.Type
}

func (f *Factory) Register(v interface{}) {
    vt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    n := vt.Name()
    f.m[n] = vt
    f.m["[]"+n] = reflect.SliceOf(vt) // implicitly register a slice of type too
}
```

these types can be looked up by name at runtime and initialized with `JSON` data:

```
func (f *Factory) Make(k string, bs []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    vt, ok := f.m[k]
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("type %q not registered", k)
    }

    pv := reflect.New(vt).Interface()

    err := json.Unmarshal(bs, pv)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return pv, nil
}
```

To use:

```
type Place struct {
    City string `json:"city"`
}

factory.Register(Place{})

p, err := factory.Make("Place", []byte(`{"city":"NYC"}`))

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p) // &main.Place{City:"NYC"}
```

Slices also work:

```
ps, err := factory.Make("[]Place", []byte(`[{"city":"NYC"},{"city":"Dublin"}]`))

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p, p) // &[]main.Place{main.Place{City:"NYC"}, main.Place{City:"Dublin"}}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qWEdwk-YUug

Comment: Updated answer to implicitly support slices of registered types.